# Building a matrix $[a_{ij}]_{3\times 3}$ where $a_{ij}\in{0,1}\,\,1\leq i,j \leq3$

Tags: probability, matrices

Let $A$ be a matrix suhc that $A=[a_{ij}]_{3\times 3}$ where $a_{ij}\in{0,1}\,\,1\leq i,j \leq3$.

Let $\sum_{k=1}^3 a_{ik}=s_i$ and $\sum_{k=1}^3 a_{kj}=t_i$. We need to find the probability that the product $P=\Pi_{k=1}^3(s_it_i)$ is an odd integer.

Now after building matrix and doing observations, I got to know that the matrix we need is such that there must be only one $1s$ per a row and column passing through $1$. But I have difficulty in counting all such matrices, and require help here, also tell if my approach is wrong here, or if you have a better approach.

Comment: But doesn't the matrix of all $1$s also have an odd $P$?

Comment: A simpler way to put this would seem to be: what is the probability that none of the row and column sums are even?

Comment: @kimchilover Yes I missed that case.

Comment: @Semiclassical Yes, but I am having difficulty in counting the cases.